# Joining a semi-related entity in JPQL

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink, jpql

Ok ... I have three entities: `A, B, C`

`A` has no relation on either `B` or `C`.

```java
@Entity
class A{
}
```

`B` has an `A` but knows nothing about `C`

```java
@Entity
class B {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    A a;

    @Column(name = "sequence")
    String sequence;
}
```

`C` is said to match `A` if `A` is associated with a `B` that has the same `sequence` value as `C`

```java
@Entity
class C {
    @Column(name = "sequence")
    String sequence;
}
```

I now want to find all unique IDs of `A` where some filter applies.
Let's set that filter to `TRUE`, for the time being.

In SQL, I might write something like this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT a.id
    FROM 
        a a
        LEFT JOIN b b ON b.a_id = a.id
        LEFT JOIN c c ON c.sequence = b.sequence
    WHERE
        (TRUE)
;
```

(cf. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e14a14707409bf667bc7544c5efea1d7 )

Now let's try the same in JPQL...

`(TRUE)` is "not a valid conditional expression", apparently, so let's switch it out for `(1 = 1)`. The rest is fairly similar:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id
    FROM 
        A a
        LEFT JOIN B b ON b.a.id = a.id
        LEFT JOIN C c ON c.sequence = b.sequence
    WHERE
        (1 = 1)
```

... or at least that's what I'd have expected to work.

Let's get an `EntityManager` and create a query ...

```kotlin
inNewTransaction { em ->    
    val query = """
                SELECT DISTINCT a.id
                FROM
                    A a
                    LEFT JOIN B b ON b.a.id = a.id
                    LEFT JOIN C c ON c.sequence = b.sequence
                WHERE
                    (1 = 1)
            """.trimIndent()

    em.createQuery(query, Int::class.java).resultList
}
```

where

```kotlin
/**Creates a new [EntityManager] using the [entityManagerFactory] and passes it to [action].
 * Wraps execution of [action] in a transaction and closes the [EntityManager] after execution
 * before the result is returned.*/
private fun <Result> inNewTransaction(action: (EntityManager) -> Result): Result {
    with(entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()) {
        transaction.begin()
        val result = action(this)
        transaction.commit()
        close()
        return result
    }
}
```

and `private val entityManagerFactory: EntityManagerFactory` was injected by Spring.

I'd expect this to generate the same kind of query as I wrote in psql above, just parameterised.

Instead, what gets generated is

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.6.v20200131-b7c997804f):
    org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:
        ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "t3" Position: 78
        Error Code: 0 Call: 
            SELECT DISTINCT t0.ID
            FROM
                a t0 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN b t1 ON (t3.ID = t0.ID)
                LEFT OUTER JOIN c t2 ON (t2.sequence = t1.sequence),
                a t3
            WHERE ((? = ?) AND (t3.ID = t1.a_id))
        bind => [2 parameters bound]
```

So

```
LEFT JOIN B b ON b.a.id = a.id
```

will not be translated to a simple join condition.
Instead, JPA will shove another `a` into the `FROM` clause, cross join it with our `b` and then filter out all entries that don't line up with the `a` we originally wanted.

Or at least that's what it seems to want to do until it gets bored halfway through and insists that the from clause it added is missing.

> missing FROM-clause entry for table "t3"

Now why does it do that?

And more importantly, how do I get this query to work?

Comment: "LEFT JOIN B b ON b.a.id = a.id", the 'b.a.id' is defining yet another inner join from b->A outside of the 'a' you already defined and are trying to use in this outer join definition. You want to just use the A relationship; try "LEFT JOIN B b ON b.a = a" instead, or define a basic mapping for the a_ID foreign key you can use here.

Comment: @Chris That seems to have done the trick, thank you. Do you want to make an answer out of the comment? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA specification requires providers use an inner join when ever dot '.' are specified for relationships. This forces the 'b.a.id' within the "LEFT JOIN B b ON b.a.id = a.id", to be interpreted as yet another inner join from b->A outside of the 'a' you already defined and are trying to use in this outer join definition.

You want to just use the A relationship; try "LEFT JOIN B b ON b.a = a" instead, or define a basic mapping for the a_ID foreign key you can use here.